# Python; exception aware map()

Tags: python, exception, functional-programming, map-function

I'm doing some pyplotting of *generic data* and converting it from a power value to a dB value. Due to the system these values come from, 0 is used as a 'the useful data ends here' indicator (the nature of the mathematics, not a defined value).

My usual way of dealing with these is wrapping the conversion in a try/except and returning a default 'low' value, eg

```
def f(value):
    try:
        return convert(value)
    except ValueError:
        return -140 #implementation specific, don't worry
```

This is fine and dandy for 90% of use within my framework, except when it comes to graphing.

I'm lazy so what I do at the minute is:

```
pl.plot(xvals,map(f,yvals))
```

This draws the data correctly, and when the data ends, plunges off a cliff, which is the expected behaviour. But what I would like to happen is for the graph to just *end* when it meets a ValueError exception and do away with f() altogether.

Other than breaking the map up into a loop, anyone got any brilliant ideas?

UPDATES:

I'm using Pylab / MatplotLib
"Endpoint" is execution dependent; sometimes the above doesn't matter atall as there are no 'bad' values. This is all in an effort for me to be lazy and use matplotlibs graph scaling instead of resetting dynamic ylim's based on the min of the ydata (which I don't do atm, just ylim(-140) in this case.)

Vaguely Important Update On Answer:
unutbu's answer is what I'll actually be using for my implementation, due to (not mentioned in the question dependencies), as raising a StopIteration in this regularly used function wreaks havoc with unrelated-to-the-question control logic, without putting all of those other instances in try-excepts; sometimes -inf makes more sense than you would think.

Thanks to everyone for being awesomely fast, and I apologise to unutbu for the QuestionFail.

Comment: the question is a bit unclear. can you show what it would look like if you did break up the map into a loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps there's some trick in the plotting library, but a much better options seems not generating such data to begin with. It's not that `map` saves you thirty lines of code...

Use `itertools.takewhile(lambda y: y != NO_VALUE, (f(y) for y in yvals))` (and wrap it in a call to `list` if the plotting library requires a list instead of an iterable).

Edit: I had an even better idea: In the wrapper, add

```
except ValueError:
    raise StopIteration
```

That's the exception signaling "end of iterale", and `map` respects it.

Comment: A note on the old solution, imap() is an iterator version of map(), so that one can use takewhile without having to run through all data. Requires recent Python version however.

Comment: @Gustav Larsson: `map` is to list comprehensions as `imap` is to generator expressions. And I'm using generator expressions whenever I can, including here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `matplotlib`, then it implies you have `numpy` installed.

Since you are converting to `dB`, it sounds like you might be taking a log. In that case, `np.log(0) = -inf`.

You can mask nans and infs with the numpy function [np.ma.masked_invalid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.fix_invalid.html#numpy.ma.fix_invalid), and `matplotlib` can plot masked arrays. For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xvals=np.arange(100)
yvals=np.cumsum(np.random.random(100))
yvals[-10:]=0
yvals=np.log(yvals)

print(yvals[-10:])
# [-Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf]

yvals=np.ma.masked_invalid(yvals)
plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Notice that the graph ends with `xval` equal to 89, since the last 10 values of `yval` are masked.

Comment: In this case its log10 but I like where this is going. Will investigate and update (unless you or anyone else beats me to it!)

Comment: I'm actually using you're answer but strictly speaking, my stripped-of-other-dependencies question was answered with the StopIteration response.

Comment: No worries; glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're needlessly limiting yourself by refusing to use a looping construct.

In your situation you want to stop iterating over data when a certain value is reached, that is exactly the purpose of `forloops` and `breaks`

```
yvals_ = []
for y in yvals:
    y_ = f(y)
    if y_ == -140:
        break
    else:
        yvals_.append(y_)

p1.plot(xvals[:len(yvals_)],yvals_)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have data, and you don't want to plot the last point. So what about not plotting it?

```
pl.plot(xvals[:-1], map(f, yvals)[:-1])
```

Comment: This will just cut off the last item. Did OP state that it's always just the last item containing bogus data?

Comment: @delnan: that's what i understood: "This draws the data correctly, and when the data ends, plunges off a cliff". if it's not always the last item then your method would be appropriate